# Set bottom position of element based on rendered height of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is the url to my website

http://projectilepixels.com/beta/

I need the space shuttle to appear "naturally positioned" i.e slightly below the grass at all resolutions above 786 x 1024. However as the grass image as it's width set to 100%, the height is dynamic. Thus the bottom value for the shuttle would also be dynamic. I had initially tried using a simple css % value but that didn't help.

My current attempt uses JavaScript. Following is the code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var grass = $( '#grass' );
    var grassHeight = grass.outerHeight() - grass.outerHeight()/100 * 74;
        $( '#shuttle_1' ).css("bottom",grassHeight);
    });
</script>
```

The initial script just used

```
var grassHeight = grass.outerHeight();
```

however it ended up really messed up.

So, as a temp fix I added the mathematics's that calculates 74% (a solution I didn't really want to use as it uses magic numbers), it seemed to work "fine" on Mozilla at 786 x 1024, however I tested it on chrome at a slightly higher resolution (Can't remember it right now, will check the specific resolution and edit this part soon). I'm new to JavaScript and am under as to what would be the best practice to solve this problem across all browsers and resolutions

Would really appreciate if someone guided me around this problem. I'm open to using css,Javascript as well as jquery.

Comment: Ok I think my question was not clear enough, problem is, the grass image width is set to `100%` making it's height dynamic based on the screen resolution. This means the bottom value for the shuttle would also be dynamic(computed based on the rendered height of grass).

Comment: It would help a lot it your grass image was actually the height of the grass... it has a lot of transparent height... If it was just the grass, you would set it inside a div, and set the shuttle on the top of it

Comment: I can fix that, but the height would still be dynamic as it's width would change based on resolution and I have set to maintain aspect ration

Comment: Can't believe how dumb I have been the whole time, the problem is fixed simply by cropping the additional tranparent area on top. Thanks @LcSalazar for pointing this out. My bad I didn't understand well. I am choosing  JRulle's answer as it's a closest match to what I ultimately implemented. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you develop a few constant values that can be applied to the actual rendered values of the grass image to adjust the placement. Something like:

Lets say the grass image is 500px x 237px but the height of the grass is only 158px – If we want the shuttle to sit right at the crown of the grass, it needs to be offset from the bottom of the screen by 158px – 158 divided by 237 works out (almost magically) to .66667

Since this is a fixed ratio, we can use .66667 to calculate the offset from the bottom of the screen for any size grass image, as long as we know the dimensions of the grass image by multiplying the height and .6667

```
$(function(){
   var OFFSET = .66667; //this value is our shuttle adjustment constant
   $( '#shuttle_1' ).css("bottom",($('#grass').height() * OFFSET)); //sets the bottom offset of the shuttle
   $( '#shuttle_1' ).css("left",(($('#grass').width()/2)-($( '#shuttle_1' ).width()/2))); //centers the shuttle
});
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/FE7CX/) demonstrating it.

Comment: If you crop the grass image, you will need to calculate a new OFFSET constant (depending on how you crop it, your offset constant might be equal to the exact height of the grass)

Answer (score 1):

i would have deffently use $.position in here,

```
$("#Grass").position({
    of: $(shuttle),
    my: "top center",
    at: "bottom center"
});
```

that will locate the the grass top line of the grass (its center), below the center of the bottom line on the shuttle

Comment: This works well if the grass image was only as tall as the grass, but the image the OP is using has about 1/3 of it's total height transparent at the top.

Comment: A very strange thing, with the "extended transparency" on top, this trick seemed to work perfectly. Now I have cropped that area and it stopped working(the shuttle renders way below the grass) PS: Thanks @JRulle and LcSalazer for pointing out my dumbness with the image's transparency. Don't know how I missed out on something like this.

Comment: Another issue that occurred when implementing this solution is, the parallax plugin seems to have no effect on the shuttle element. So it didnt move a pixel on scroll (more like it had it's `position` set to `fixed`